# How to secure an open port and public IP address when clients must connect to it

Tags: network, ports, threat-mitigation

I do not have a lot of experience in networking, however, I have built a live-chat application using socket.io and nodeJS. In order to do this, I had to open a port to allow other networks to connect. How can I ensure that the open port does not leave vulnerabilities?

Also since the client is connecting to my public IP are they able to see it?

Comment: *"Also since the client is connecting to my public IP are they able to see it?"* - sure, otherwise they could not connect to it. It is like somebody writing a letter to you - they have to know your address first.

Comment: To cite [Vulnerability of the open port](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35791/vulnerability-of-the-open-port): *"An open port is not a security vulnerability in itself. It allows an attacker to connect and exploit any vulnerabilities in the process that's running. The answer to your question depends on how sure you are in security of your service. "*. In other words: To insure that the open port does not leave vulnerabilities you have to ensure the security of your application. Not enough is known about your application to make any recommendations about its security.

Comment: With regard to ensuring that your program listening on the open port does not have vulnerabilities, a lot can be learned from Daniel Bernstein, author of qmail.  See https://cr.yp.to/qmail/guarantee.html and https://cr.yp.to/qmail/qmailsec-20071101.pdf.